# How WordPress select database engine while installing website?

Tags: wordpress, mysql-cluster

Is this default database storage engine? I want to install my WordPress website with MYSQL "NDB CLUSTER" storage engine. I tried to install wordpress site, but it's installed with InnoDB. Please help me to resolve this.

I used this SET storage_engine=NDBCLUSTER;  in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to migrate InnoDB tables with foreign keys to NDB.

```
    Dump the database and edit the script so each table specifies ENGINE=NDB before re-importing the script to a new database
    Drop the constraints, alter the tables to use the NDB engine, and recreate the constraints

Dumping the database and editing the script is a straightforward use of mysqldump and a text editor.
```

[Converting InnoDB Tables to MySQL Cluster](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/innodb_to_mysql_cluster)

it might helpful for you